# Creating a new connection on interface not used before using nmcli

Tags: networkmanager

Trying to setup a new connection using nmcli. The system is debian wheezy, the platform ci20.

I am missing an ID or UUID parameter in order to perform nmcli con up [id | uuid ]

It complains about this argument missing, but since no connection was made through this interface before I don't seem to be able to get it anywhere.

When I do nmcli con it spits out two previous connections on a different interface.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, not sure, kinda stuck. Maybe I should be doing something else entirely in order to achieve what I want to achieve, not sure.

No gui present, would prefer to set it from the command line interface if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of network-manager? the feature was apparently added in 0.9.6.0 ("Add ability to connect to new WiFi networks from nmcli"). See this [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186705/65304).

Comment: That answers it, I am using 0.9.4.1 version of nm. I was only looking at the manual page and I never would have guessed such an important feature could have been missing. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mr. steeldriver kindly suggested I was using the old version of nm and this feature was only added in 0.9.6.0 ("Add ability to connect to new WiFi networks from nmcli"). Damn you wheezy.