# Centos 6.7 in a laptop does not detect network interfaces but detect network hardware

Tags: centos, network-interface, networkmanager, laptop

I am installing **CentOS 6.7** in my **laptop**, I have Windows 10, Centos 6.7 and Ubuntu 18 installed, but CentOS is the only OS that is **not detecting any network interface**, wired neither wifi.

I used **NetworkManager** to automatic configuration, but it seems that is **not being able to configure it**.

My laptop is a MSI GE60-20E. **SN**: GE60 2OE-223XESK1402000204

**Outputs** are: (sorry for quality, I don't have any internet on my laptop in CentOS)

[image: Networks]

I need to  configure it. Windows and Ubuntu is detecting everything.

**UPDATE** new outputs with `nmcli`

[image: Other outputs]

Comment: is it a newer MSI laptop? I have the MSI ps42 and CentOS 7.5 worked on it.

Comment: Is not new, it has an i5-4200U. I bought in 2014 May. SN: GE60 2OE-223XESK1402000204

Comment: `ls -la /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` do you have any configurations already setup? if not, you may have to set that up.

Comment: The thing is, that I don't know which to configure because usually is **eth0** or **wlan0**, and the system does not recognize those interfaces. I mean, I create `etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and configure it but nothing happens.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186705/how-do-i-use-nmcli-to-create-a-wifi-connection-connect-to-ssid-over-wpa

Comment: why are you putting CentOS 6.7? You could use CentOS 7 on your system.

Comment: Well, I was considering on using CentOS 6.10, I'm doing some Hadoop Ecosystem configuration, and everywhere I go, they use CentOS (Cloudera Quickstart is using CentOS 6.7). So I thought it was a good idea using the same OS everybody use for Hadoop Ecosystem... @thebtm

Comment: Minimal support was added in [vanilla kernel 3.10](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ab69bde6b2e9c37456eeb0051a185446336aef9f) : chances are this would work on CentOS 7 (not 6.x) instead.

Comment: Okay seems that I should use Fedora or CentOS 7 but I have to test in a VM before. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: wifi: perhaps kernel 3.8+ required https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTL8723AE.html

Answer (score 0):

`eth0` is for the wired connection
`wlan0` is for the wireless connection

For configuring a network connection, if it hasn't already been completed automatically, there is a few ways you can go about it from the command line and from the GUI (though I dont have that information handy at the moment)

If you are missing the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` then you have to tell nmcli to create the connections, it helps to do checks before you actually start making connections.

Starting with an `nmcli dev show` to make sure you can see all the hardware with `nmcli`

```
[root@linux-repository ~]# nmcli dev show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     eth0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         X.X.X.X/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            X.X.X.X
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = X.X.X.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = X.X.X.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             X.X.X.X
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.4.4

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

then you want to see if you can see already configured connections with `nmcli con show`

```
[root@linux-repository ~]# nmcli con show
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
eth0  0c7ab467-dbdf-41c2-b3a3-882760879594  ethernet  eth0
```

once you have the device name from `nmcli dev show` just add a generic connection with `nmcli con add type ethernet con-name <dev name> ifname <dev name>` and this should add a dhcp connection to your wired connection to help get you going to be online again; for wireless, I recommend checking out a nmtui tutorial.

```
[root@linux-repository ~]# nmcli con add type ethernet con-name eth0 ifname eth0
Connection 'eth0' (058aac84-c024-46bc-9847-b6e8044fb9c6) successfully added.
```

#### NMCLI & NMTUI

[CentOS 7 Network Configuration Using nmtui Tool](https://systemzone.net/centos-7-network-configuration-using-nmtui-tool/) here is an CentOS tutorial on nmcli
[RHEL 7 nmcli](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-Configuring_IP_Networking_with_nmcli)   [this is pretty much the same as the nmcli for RHEL 6, Centos 7 & 6]
also can run `man nmcli` the manual for the tool is also on the system.

#### ifcfg

[How To Configure Static IP On CentOS 6](https://www.walmartphotocentre.ca/home_splash.aspx)
an example of setting up a network via the ifcfg files, you may have to add the NM_CONTROLLED="no" if you dont want network manager to mess with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting some empty outputs with nmcli. `nmcli dev` empty list, `nmcli con` empty list. With configuration files I create the `ifcfg-eth0` file, with `device=eth0`, and then restarting the networks, but it doesn't up the interface because it doesn't exist.

Comment: on the question, can you attach the `nmcli dev show`

Comment: `nmcli dev show` says that **dev show** is not a valid command.

Comment: I'm going to post those outputs I got in question, give me some minutes please. Thanks.

Comment: the `nmcli con add` command should still work. if your device is named `eth0`

Comment: updated the qeustion